# Modern TeX/LaTeX Literate Programming Tool?

Tags: c++, latex

Originally posted on the TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388092/modern-literate-programming-tool).  Note that I had to remove some links due to not having enough reputation here to include them yet.

---

I've been meaning to do some literate programming in the near future, so I did a Google search for it and came upon [this web page of tool recommendations](http://www.literateprogramming.com/tools.html), which at first looked like a good listing.  Upon further inspection, however, my initial impressions of it proved to be somewhat rushed and naïve, as it doesn't exactly seem to state unequivocally which of the tools it lists is the most standard, commonly accepted best practice, or most modern I should work with.  From what I've read around the Web so far, the original WEB was for Pascal and CWEB was for C, but both are obsolete.
     Neither of these would help me, though, since I need something that works with C++, specifically that language's 2011, 2014, and upcoming 2017 revisions.  *That* consideration, therefore, left `noweb` to me as a prominent option.  I was going to use it, but then, alas, I discovered to my chagrin that it, *too*, is deemed obsolete, at least by the watermark on its CTAN listing, and, according to its homepage, has not seen a new release for over *six years!*  Given *this* unpleasant surprise, can anybody recommend me a more modern literate-programming tool or toolchain usable with LaTeX that is still seeing developer maintenance to use?

Comment: TeX.SX has a lot of questions on [literate programming](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literate-programming); your question would certainly be on-topic there.

Comment: [On the contrary, the folks there disagree…](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388092/modern-literate-programming-tool#comment962378_388092)

Comment: Just edited my question to clarify that I'm looking for this kind of language support, mirroring an identical edit I made to the version of this version of it that's still on the TeX/LaTeX SE.